# Ruby/Rails - Shrine::Error (storage :store isn't registered on ImageUploader)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shrine

For the last days, I'm trying to add a new storage config for my application, so we can use Cloudinary for images and Digital Ocean Spaces for other files.
And after the changes I supposed were needed for that, when I try to access a old model's attribute that's associated to an ImageUploader's Attacher, I get the this error:

`Shrine::Error (storage :store isn't registered on ImageUploader)`

The thing is: I dont have a storage "store" defined, indeed, but that's because I'm trying to have a `image_store` and a `raw_store`.

Here is my `config/initializers/shrine.rb`:

```
# config/initializers/shrine.rb
require "shrine"
require "shrine/storage/file_system"
require "shrine/storage/cloudinary"
require "shrine/storage/s3"

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data # for retaining the cached file across form redisplays
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data # re-extract metadata when attaching a cached file
Shrine.plugin :rack_file # for non-Rails apps
Shrine.plugin :default_storage, store: :image_store

s3_options = {
  access_key_id: ENV['DO_SPACE_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['DO_SPACE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  bucket: ENV['DO_SPACE_SECRET_BUCKET'],
  endpoint: "https://#{ENV['REGION']}.digitaloceanspaces.com",
  region: ENV['REGION']
}

if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  Shrine.storages = {
    raw_cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/raw_cache"), # temporary
    raw_store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/raw_store"),       # permanent
    image_cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/image_cache"), # temporary
    image_store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/image_store")       # permanent
  }
else
  Shrine.storages = {
    raw_cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(
      prefix: "raw_cache", upload_options: { acl: 'public-read' }, **s3_options
    ), # for direct uploads
    raw_store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(
      prefix: "raw_store", upload_options: { acl: 'public-read' }, **s3_options
    ),
    image_cache: Shrine::Storage::Cloudinary.new(prefix: "image_cache", resource_type: 'image'), # for direct uploads
    image_store: Shrine::Storage::Cloudinary.new(prefix: "image_store", resource_type: 'image'),
  }
end
```

And here is my ImageUploader:

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  plugin :default_storage, cache: :image_cache, store: :image_store
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :data_uri
  plugin :infer_extension

  plugin :upload_options, store: ->(io, context) do
    [...]
  end

  plugin :url_options, store: -> (io, **options) do
    [...]
  end

  # I even tried that one, but no success
  Attacher.default_store :image_store

  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size 5*1024*1024, message: "is too large (max is 5 MB)"
  end
end
```

Could anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem.

At first, I used to have only 2 storages in my Shrine initializer:

```
[...]
Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::Cloudinary.new(prefix: "image_cache", resource_type: 'image'), # for direct uploads
  store: Shrine::Storage::Cloudinary.new(prefix: "image_store", resource_type: 'image'),
  }
[...]
```

And for that reason, now that I'm updating my storages, when I recover a record that was saved before, it's saved with "storage: store" in the attachment field, which doesn't match anymore with the old store's cloudinary configuration.

So, what it seems that what I need to do is: update storage's field of any file column I have in my DB, so it will match current configs.